# Getting Username and Password from a file(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program that allows me to get a username and password from a file. I feel like I am on the right track but, when I run the program to test whether or not it works, I get a:

> Name error: global name Username is not defined.

Any ideas where I've gone wrong? I apologize if the formatting is off.

```
    def login():
        UserName = input("Please enter your user name: ")
        passw = input("Please enter your password: ")
        check(UserName, passw)
        return UserName, passw

    def check(user, password):
        pword = {}
        for line in open('unames_passwords.txt','r'):
            user, password = line.split()
            pword[user] = password
            if user == UserName and password == passw:
               return True
               print("Thank you for logging in.")
            else:
               print("Username or password is incorrect")

    def main():
        login()

    main()
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.  You must _hash_ your passwords.

Comment: @SLaks **Do not give unsolicited advice without supplying an explanation.** - There, I can write things in bold too! But seriously, if you feel the need to comment on security issues of an obvious toy application please at least share your reasoning, instead of just writing a statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `check` function doesn't have any variable named `UserName`.
Instead, it has a parameter named `user`, which is then overridden by the line from the file.

You need to change the parameter to a unique name, then use that name.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm just trying to figure out how to stop the print statement from repeating.

Comment: @user3107805: It sounds like you only want to print if you don't find _any_ matching rows (meaning, after you finish looking at all of the rows), rather than for each non-matching row.

Comment: Any advice on how I would go about doing that?

Comment: You need to understand when each line executes, depending on whether it's inside the loop or after it.